# How exactly does proof by contradiction work in this circumstance? (Proving property of Lebesgue Integral)

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I would like to prove the following property of the lebesgue integral:

Proposition $1.12$ Suppose $f$ is integrable on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Then for every $\epsilon>0$ :
(i) There exists a set of finite measure $B$ (a ball, for example) such that

$$\int_{B^{c}}|f|<\epsilon$$

I don't need help proving it, as there is a proof in the textbook. But I was wondering how you could prove this by contradiction - because I *thought* you could find quite an easy contradiction proof, which is:

*b.w.o.c assume that if for every $\epsilon$, for every set B with finite measure*

$$\int_{B^c} |f| \ge \epsilon$$

And since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily large, then clearly $f$ is not integrable.

I know this is wrong, but I'm having trouble seeing exactly where - I know it's something to do with trying to generate the proper converse statement.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: The contrapostive should be “There exists an $\epsilon_0 >0$ such that for every set …”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The negation of "for every $\varepsilon$, (something is true about $\varepsilon$)" is not "for every $\varepsilon$, (something is false about $\varepsilon$)" as you have written, but rather "*there exists* $\varepsilon$ such that (something is false about $\varepsilon$)".